# Understand VSYSCALL_ADDR and function pointer

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I came across the following code. I have two questions here. 
1. where to find this __NR_vgetcpu? What other values could I get by callign VSYSCALL_ADDR?
2. What does this line "my_getpuc =( int(*)) .....)" do?

```
int (*my_getcpu)(unsigned *cpu, unsigned *node, struct getcpu_cache *tcache);
char *addr3 = (char *)VSYSCALL_ADDR(__NR_vgetcpu);
printf("vgetcpu addr is %p \n", addr3);
my_getcpu = (int (*)(unsigned *, unsigned *, struct getcpu_cache *))addr3;
my_getcpu(&cpu, &node, &cache);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily find these using `grep` or `ack` or `ag`

For the first question, I greped and find it appeared in the file `arch/x86/include/asm/vsyscall.h`

```
enum vsyscall_num {
    __NR_vgettimeofday,
    __NR_vtime,
    __NR_vgetcpu,
};

#define VSYSCALL_START (-10UL << 20)
#define VSYSCALL_SIZE 1024
#define VSYSCALL_END (-2UL << 20)
#define VSYSCALL_MAPPED_PAGES 1
#define VSYSCALL_ADDR(vsyscall_nr) (VSYSCALL_START+VSYSCALL_SIZE*(vsyscall_nr))
```

So `__NR_vgetcpu` is `2`
`VSYSCALL_ADDR(__NR_vgetcpu)` is `(-10UL << 20) + 1024 * 2` equals to `0xff600800`

For the second question, the line `my_getcpu =( int(*)) .....)` cast `0xff600800` to a function pointer(which has 3 arguments and returns int) and assigned it to `my_getcpu` so that `my_getcpu` can be treated like a function in the next line.

Comment: Side note: `git grep` much better than plain `grep`.